# How do I Change Magento Theme URL?

Tags: magento

I’m using free Magento template and `Quick installation` (Copy the Files/Dump the Database)

Now the template path is set to

`/app/design/frontend/template_name`

How can i change it to

`/app/design/frontend/default/tempate_name`

Where they defind the path to template..

Anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply goto `System->Configuration->General->Design->Theme`.Here you can set your theme while on `Package` tab you can set your Package name.

Answer (score 0):

System->design->add desing change->Custom Design->select your package

Answer (score 0):

> **Below define Image step to follow for your selected theme to apply on
>   your site.**

[image]